# printf crashes while printing float values

Tags: c++, c, printf

I ran into a weird problem with `printf()` today. But I couldn't find its answer even after analyzing it. Hence sharing it here. I tried these three `printf()` statements:

```
printf("\nValue of this division is %f", (double)873/(double)65);
```

It prints correct output as expected.

```
printf("\nSome message with an integer here %d followed by floats %f, %f, %f", 2013, 987/432, 873/65, 983/81);
```

Given me wrong values (Because I didn't cast them to double?)

```
printf("\nSome message with an integer here %d followed by floats %f, %f, %f and now string at end: %s", 2013, 987/432, 873/65, 983/81, "Some trial string here");
```

`printf()` crashed here! And this raises me two questions:

1. I saw the "FormatOutput(LPCSTR formatstring, ...)" example given in MSDN in which they allocate fixed width destination buffer then call `vsnprintf()` with it. I believe `printf()` works along the same line. But I didn't find anywhere internal buffer size of `printf()`. If it dynamically allocates memory, how does it then calculates buffer size?
2. `printf()` crashes on above line because `vsnprintf()` also crashes there (Yes I tried `FormatOutput` sample code given for `vsnprintf()` with above parameters). But why would would it crash ultimately?

Comment: You're casting to `double`, try casting to `float`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, Don't they get promoted anyway?

Comment: `printf` doesn't know what its parameters are meant to be.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter: Variable argument lists convert `float`s to `double` first thing, if I recall correctly.

Comment: ok, move along, nothing to see here :)

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I keep forgetting about those promotions myself, or mixing them up and saying the opposite of what happens.

Comment: @Andrew: You might want to check your compiler switches. I know gcc is actually capable of parsing `printf (...)` format strings at compile-time and validating the list of arguments you pass, and I believe I have seen newer versions of Microsoft Visual C do this as well. With the right switches, they can be set to warn you for doing things like this. _(Passing integer values when the format expects double)_

Comment: @Andrew printf with format string is evil, you incorrectly write the format string may have later impacter (for example, the later data are print incorrectly, or even have security issue). If not for performance issue and language allowed, suggest you using std::cout.

Comment: @ZijingWu: I am using it especially for logging purpose. Performance is very imp here. With the format I form the log string using vsnprintf and then dump it either on screen or in DB (depend on flag). Are you suggesting it for all printf family or only to printf function?

Comment: @Andrew I'm saying format string. Whenever you using format string. It need super careful, including objective-c NSLog. You can find more detail here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("\nSome message with an integer here %d followed by floats %f, %f, %f and now string at end: %s", 2013, 987/432, 873/65, 983/81, "Some trial string here");
```

As explained by earlier answers, the result of an integer division is an integer. So `987/432` would result in a *(most likely)* 32-bit `int` on your system. But `%f` tells `printf` to expect a 64-bit `double`! Thus, it reads the combined memory space of `987/432` and `873/65` - giving garbage result. And following that, another 64-bit `double`: `983/81` and pointer to `"Some..."` - garbage again.

Another 64-bit double (the third `%f`) follows, which is now out of bounds! It's probably luck that your second example didn't crash right there. By the time it reaches `%s`, `printf()` would look for a pointer... if it doesn't crash from the out of bounds access, it would from trying to access invalid memory address of the resulting pointer.

1. `printf()` doesn't need to allocate memory. It writes directly to the standard output (e.g. your terminal window)
2. Any variation of the the `printf` family would crash just the same.

Comment: "It writes directly to the standard output" .. indeed :-) I was wrong by assuming printf internally first prepares its output using vsnprintf. But it doesn't really need to do that.

Answer (score 6):

You promised to print `double`s but you are passing in `int`s: `987/432` is an `int`. If you want this value to be a `double` you'd use `987.0/432`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

your arguments `2013, 987/432, 873/65, 983/81' are all ints!

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `(double)873/(double)65` for casting, simply you can use `(double)873/65` or even `873.0/65`. And dividing an `int` by an `int` will always result in `int` value. To print `double`, you can use `987.0/432` or simply `987f/432` for printing `float`.  Both will work.

Comment: In theory, `987f/432` might give a different answer from `987.0/432` because one is calculated as a `float` and then converted to a `double` and the other is calculated as a `double`.  With a plain `%f` format, you wouldn't notice the difference; with `%.15f`, you might well notice it.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you are supplying the results of integer division to `printf (...)` when it expects double-precision floating-point. Either use single- or double-precision floating-point division or correct your format string. Note that single-precision floating-point is [automatically promoted](http://c-faq.com/varargs/promos.html) to double-precision, just as char and short are promoted to int when used in conjunction with variable argument lists.

As a thought experiment, you should consider the myriad of things that *may* happen in a hypothetical scenario where you cast a pointer from a 32-bit data type to 64-bit type and then attempt to dereference it. Just as in the pointer scenario illustrated above, you are dealing with undefined behavior as a result of improperly communicating your data types. There are a number of nasty things that can occur and cause your program to crash if you invoke undefined behavior.

Nevertheless, some compilers are capable of parsing your format string at compile-time and validating it against the list of arguments you supply `printf (...)`. You may want to look at the available compiler warnings on your system so you can avoid this in the future.

Comment: I'm puzzled by your comment _'One need only consider what may happen when you cast a pointer from a 32-bit data type to 64-bit and attempt to dereference it to understand why this has the potential to cause crashes.'_ There are no pointers involved in this question. If you said something like: 'Consider what happens when you pass three 4-byte `int` values when you tell `printf()` it will be given three 8-byte `double` values, and you will realize that it will access data that was not passed, in a format that was not expected, and odd results or crashes can be expected', then I'd be unpuzzled.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did not say that, because there is no guarantee that integer is a 4-byte type or that a byte is 8-bit. It was to hint the question asker at undefined behavior. I did not say this is what was happening, just that he consider the type of situation that arises in this scenario.

Comment: True; were it my answer, I'd have added caveats about 'under the assumption that the sizes of ...' but that doesn't fit into the comment very easily.  While you mention pointers as if pointers were a factor in the code in the question, I can't up-vote your answer — even though there is some other good material in it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Good point, I was looking for a quick and easy way to demonstrate another situation in which the compiler cannot enforce or even recognize violations of incompatible types and pointers were the first thing that came to mind. I have also implemented `printf (...)` on platforms without a stdlib in the past and I used pointer casting of the members of the `va_arg` list based on the format string. Hopefully the edit is clearer.